# Truck Animation document.querySelector is null

Tags: angular, typescript, null, listener, web-frontend

I found this cool animation [Truck Animation Button](https://codemyui.com/button-delivery-truck-animation/)
but when I click on the "Ship" Button nothing happens.

I'm trying to implement the Typescript part, but all the document.querySelector are null. 
I'm doing this OnInit() for example: 
    `this.ripple = document.querySelector('[data-anim=ripple]');`

And I always got the Error: "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: You can include your html,javascript or create a demo using snippet.

Comment: I already can fix this! Thank you! But now I have a problem... I got the error: this.getClickCoords is not a function :(

Comment: I think it's because the call to function btnHandler doesn't have any parameter and the function needs one. But I don't know what the parameter should be... Can you help me on this? Thank you :)

Comment: Without code noone can help you.